# Replace coaxial cords with ethernet

Tags: wiring, network

I recently just bought a home that had coaxial cords wired throughout the house.

I would like to use Ethernet instead but I don't want to have to rip the walls out.

I have a feeling that there is a device which exists which can follow the existing cable and snake the Ethernet cable along the same path as the coax.

Is it possible to do so, or what would be the easiest way to wire Ethernet while leveraging the existing wiring?

Comment: Sometimes, coax will have been added after construction, and might not be stapled in place.  If thats the case, you can use the coax to pull cat6.

Comment: Why don't you use the coax as a MoCA network?

Comment: @JPhi1618 good call

Comment: @Gunner what's moCa network

Comment: ethernet is dying, most everything is wifi by default these days, which now offers comparable performance to ethernet and better security. you could get a bridge to use IP over coax, but the speed is lacking and you'll need converters for each access spot; in that case, modern wifi is WAY faster. If you have a several year old router, I can understand reluctance, but they are not the same as they used to be...

Comment: @dandavis -- eh, wifi will always be limited by the infelicities of a radio physical layer...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel if i had a quarter for every time i heard "cell phones won't ever replace landlines because ___ ___ ____", I'd have a few bucks ;). Fact is wifi is getting faster faster than copper. Cheap wifi beats out GBE these days, and expensive wifi can give what some call 10GBE a run for the money. Wifi's plenty fast for most applications which is why jacks are disappearing; the future is clear.

Comment: @dandavis -- its less bandwidth and more latency, jitter, and signal interference constraints

Comment: @dandavis I can hack your WiFi from outside your house (it may take a while, but it's possible). The only way I can hack your cabled network is to get inside your house and plug into it. First rule of security: once they have physical access they own the device. ;) Speed wise, things may be leaning toward wireless, but physical cables will beat radio waves for security every time.

Comment: Wired internet will always be more secure and faster than WIFI. Just a couple of years ago, when my wife got ROKU, she connected with wifi (she wanted to do it herself). It was terrible and we had a good WIFI router.  I said, why don't we just connect it to the hard wired RJ45 jack next to the TV.  We did that and now it's trouble free.

Next:  MoCA is Media over Coax.   It re-purposes existing COAX for network/internet purposes.   Great solution for older homes that haven't been wired with cat-5 or cat-6.

Comment: @FreeMan   Totally agree with you. Wired will be beat out wifi every time for security and speed.   And lets be real, it doesn't have to be one or the other, I have both wired and wifi in my house for convenience. My phone and laptop use WIFI and my desktop PC uses the hard wired cat-5.  I'm in a remote area so I'm not worried about people hacking into my wifi.

Comment: @FreeMan if you can hack my wifi, why are you wasting time on stack instead of saving or stealing the world? If wifi's AES is broken, so to is https' AES, in which case you can tap my coax outside my house. The first rule of encryption is that your enemy _can_ physically see everything, yet it must remain secure.

Comment: Audiophiles insisted optical toslink is better than copper because you know (unconvincing hand-waving), jitter. Now sparkys are saying electrons are actually better than photons because, you know, jitter. I just go by facts and see that most wifi criticism while applicable at some point is outmoded.

Comment: pssst... @dandavis... go look up "brute force hacking". Note, I didn't say it was fast or efficient, but that it _could be done_. ;) Anyway, we've wandered more than far enough off topic...

Comment: @dandavis Wifi is never going to be as reliable or fast as a cable connection. Yes, the latest wi-fi is faster than last decade's cable, and both are plenty fast, but some nerds are wiring their houses for 25-gigabit fiber now and you just can't get that ridiculous speed on wireless. Of course, you also can't move around the house with a cable connection, so they've both got pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such "snaking" device. There are devices that can be put at each end of a coax cable to permit internet signals. There are 2 units, A and B, that work with only one length of cable. They are usually used to allow a network camera to run on a coax line. If you run new ethernet cable, the first step is to map the existing cables and make a drawing. Then decide where you will run new cables, maybe eliminating some existing runs. You could plan for one or more wireless access points. They look like ceiling mounted routers.

Comment: If the coax in the walls is not secured, could it not be used as a fish tape, pulling cat6 or whatever through the wall?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Ethernet *originally* ran on coax cables -- but also originally ran as a switchless system where the protocol had to deal much more frequently with recovering from collisions between senders. Today's higher speeds do assume twisted-pair, and at higher speeds multiple-twisted-pair, connections to a central switch which manages data routing.

As others have noted, MoCA (Multimedia over Coax) can be used to route fairly high speed data over a coax cable. It's often used by cable companies that provide internet services; a MoCA modem, or a router with MoCA built in, is used to connect their cable to your Ethernet wiring. You *could* use MoCA more generally inside the house; interface boxes can be purchased.

Another workaround is Ethernet Over Power (as opposed to Power Over Ethernet). There are devices which will use your house wiring as a shared antenna, letting you just plug them into an outlet wherever you want an Ethernet jack. There may or may not be issues if you want to use an outlet that's on a different phase of AC. I've used these on occasion, when I needed a temporary Ethernet drop somewhere and didn't want to use WiFi or run wires; they generally won't give you the fastest possible connection, but most folks don't need the fastest possible connection most of the time.

WiFi is certainly an alternative, with WiFi boosters or "mesh" routers to reach farther places as a series of WiFi hops. Again, performance of WiFi isn't as good as wired, but for most purposes it's good enough. Since this is radio, and visible outside the house, you do want to watch your network configuration to make sure it's as secure as your hardware will let you be. On the other hand, I like being able to connect from the far corner of my back yard sometimes, and I have a lot of home automation that talks WiFi (or other radio protocols, Z-wave and Zigbee, but those need yet another kind of hardware).

So... Yeah, you can use the coax. It'll take some investment, and may not give you as good a result as if you run proper CAT5/CAT6 cables and Ethernet jacks, but it can be made to work.

Comment: Note that if you have access to the rooms from basement/crawlspace, attic, or (in the case of a 2-story building) both plus a place you can oull wires between those, running Ethernet cables is not hard. The _plugs_ are hard to attach reliably to a cable, but most jacks use simple punch-down connections and you can then use commercially manufactured jumper cables from those jacks to your router on one end and the downstream device on the other